# How to find word occurences in a workbook using macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in Excel to list out unique words and their occurence count in a given range of cells.

Is there any best way to do this?

Comment: paste range values into an array and then perform checks

Answer (score 0):

1. Copying from a comment by mehow: paste range values into an array 
   That's a good start
2. Create a Scripting.Dictionary object (requires reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**)
3. Once you have the Dictionary - loop through the array and:

   - check if an entry exists (`Dictionary.Exists`)
   - if it does not - add a key/value pair (`Dictionary.Add`), where key is your word and value is 1
   - if it does - increment the value (`Dictionary(key) = Dictionary(key) + 1`), where key is your word.
4. After that you will know how many unique words you have (`Dictionary.Count`) and you could check the occurance of each word.